# Não consigo carregar campos

Tags: java, mysql

Essa é minha tela

```
<h:panelGrid columns="6">

    <h:outputText value="Nome: * " />
    <p:inputText id="nome" value="#{funcionarioController.funcionario.nome}" size="18"
                 maxlength="80" required="true" label="Nome"
                 requiredMessage="Favor informar o nome do funcionario. Campo de preencimento obrigatório">

        <f:validateLength minimum="4" maximum="70"/>
    </p:inputText>

    <h:outputText value="Cargo: * "  />
    <p:inputText id="cargo" value="#{funcionarioController.funcionario.cargo}" size="18"
                 maxlength="80" required="true" 
                 requiredMessage="Favor informar o cargo do funcionario. Campo de preencimento obrigatório">
        <f:validateLength minimum="4" maximum="70"/>
    </p:inputText>
    <h:outputLabel value="CPF: *  "/>
    <p:inputMask id="cpf" value="#{funcionarioController.funcionario.cpf}" size="18"
                 required="true" requiredMessage="Favor informar o cpf do funcionario. Campo de preencimento obrigatório"
                 mask="999.999.999-99">
    </p:inputMask>
    <h:outputText value="RG:* " />
    <p:inputText id="rg" value="#{funcionarioController.funcionario.rg}" size="18"
                 maxlength="12" required="true" 
                 requiredMessage="Favor informar o rg do funcionario. Campo de preencimento obrigatório">
    </p:inputText>
    <h:outputText value="OrgaoExped:* " />
    <p:inputMask id="orgaoExped" value="#{funcionarioController.funcionario.orgaoExped}" size="18"
                 required="true" mask="aaa"
                 requiredMessage="Favor informar o Orgao Expedidor do funcionario. Campo de preencimento obrigatório">
    </p:inputMask>
    <h:outputText value="DataExped:" />
    <p:calendar id="dataExped" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" locale="pt_BR" size="18"/>
    <h:outputLabel value="Cor:" for="Cor"/>
    <p:selectOneMenu id="Cor" required="true" value="#{funcionarioController.funcionario.cor}" 
                     requiredMessage="Favor informar a cor do funcionario">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel=""/>
        <f:selectItem itemValue="Branco" itemLabel="Branco"/>
        <f:selectItem itemValue="Pardo" itemLabel="Pardo"/>
        <f:selectItem itemValue="Amarelo" itemLabel="Amarelo"/>
        <f:selectItem itemValue="Negro" itemLabel="Negro"/>

    </p:selectOneMenu> 

    <h:outputLabel value="Sexo: *" for="sexo"/>
    <p:selectOneMenu id="sexo"  required="true" value="#{funcionarioController.funcionario.sexo}"
                     requiredMessage="Favor informar o sexo do cliente">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel=""/>
        <f:selectItem itemValue="Masculino" itemLabel="Masculino"/>
        <f:selectItem itemValue="Feminino" itemLabel="Feminino"/>
    </p:selectOneMenu>

    <h:outputLabel value="Estado Civil:*"/>
    <p:selectOneMenu id="estadoCivil"  required="true" value="#{funcionarioController.funcionario.estadoCivil}"
                     requiredMessage="Favor informar o estado civil do funcionario. Campo de preenchimento obrigatório">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel=""/>
        <f:selectItem itemValue="Casado" itemLabel="Casado"/>
        <f:selectItem itemValue="Solteiro" itemLabel="Solteiro"/>
        <f:selectItem itemValue="Disvociado" itemLabel="Disvociado"/>
        <f:selectItem itemValue="Viúvo" itemLabel="Viúvo"/>

    </p:selectOneMenu>
    <h:outputText value="Data nascimento:" />
    <p:calendar id="dataDeNascimento" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" locale="pt_BR" size="18"/>

    <h:outputText value="CNH:" />
    <p:inputText id="cnh" value="#{funcionarioController.funcionario.cnh}" size="18"
                 maxlength="12" required="true"
                 requiredMessage="Favor informar o CNH do funcionario.">
    </p:inputText>
    <h:outputText value="Titulo:" />
    <p:inputText id="titulo" value="#{funcionarioController.funcionario.titulo}" size="18"
                 maxlength="12" required="true"
                 requiredMessage="Favor informar o CNH do funcionario.">
    </p:inputText>

    <h:outputText value="Zona:" />
    <p:inputMask id="zona" value="#{funcionarioController.funcionario.zona}" size="18"
                 required="true" mask="999"
                 requiredMessage="Favor informar o zona do funcionario.">
    </p:inputMask>
    <h:outputText value="Secao:" />
    <p:inputMask id="secao" value="#{funcionarioController.funcionario.secao}" size="18"
                 required="true" mask="999"
                 requiredMessage="Favor informar o secao do funcionario.">
    </p:inputMask>
    <h:outputText value="Pis:" />
    <p:inputText id="pis" value="#{funcionarioController.funcionario.pis}" size="18"
                 maxlength="12" required="true"
                 requiredMessage="Favor informar o pis do funcionario. Campo de preenchimento obrigatório">
    </p:inputText>
    <h:outputText value="Nº C Trabalho:" />
    <p:inputText id="carteiraDeTrabalho" label="CarteiraDeTrabalho" value="#{funcionarioController.funcionario.carteiraTrabalho}" size="18"
                 maxlength="4" required="true"
                 requiredMessage="Favor informar o numero da carteira de trabalho do funcionario. Campo de preenchimento obrigatório">
    </p:inputText>
    <h:outputText value="Sº C Trabalho:" />
    <p:inputText id="serieCTrabalho" label="SerieCTrabalho" value="#{funcionarioController.funcionario.serieCTrabalho}" size="18"
                 maxlength="4" required="true"
                 requiredMessage="Favor informar o serie da carteira de trabalho do funcionario. Campo de preenchimento obrigatório">
    </p:inputText>
    <h:outputText value="Cº Resevista:" />
    <p:inputText id="cartResevista" value="#{funcionarioController.funcionario.cartResevista}" size="18"
                 maxlength="12" required="true"
                 requiredMessage="Favor informar o numero da carteira de resevista do funcionario.">
    </p:inputText>
    <h:outputText value="Sº Resevista:" />
    <p:inputText id="serieResevista" value="#{funcionarioController.funcionario.serieResevista}" size="18"
                 maxlength="12" required="true"
                 requiredMessage="Favor informar a serie da resevista do funcionario.">
    </p:inputText>
    <h:outputText value="Nome do banco:" />
    <p:inputText id="nome_banco" value="#{funcionarioController.funcionario.nome_banco}" size="18"
                 maxlength="30" required="true" 
                 requiredMessage="Favor informar o nome do banco do funcionario.">

        <f:validateLength minimum="4" maximum="70"/>
    </p:inputText>
    <h:outputText value="Numero banco:" />
    <p:inputMask id="numero_banco" value="#{funcionarioController.funcionario.numero_banco}" size="8"
                 required="true" mask="99999999"
                 requiredMessage="Favor informar o numero do banco do funcionario.">
    </p:inputMask>
    <h:outputText value="Conta Cº:" />
    <p:inputMask id="conta_corrente" value="#{funcionarioController.funcionario.conta_corrente}" size="8"
                 required="false" mask="99.999">
    </p:inputMask>
    <h:outputText value="Agencia banco:" />
    <p:inputMask id="agencia_banco" value="#{funcionarioController.funcionario.agencia_banco}" size="8"
                 required="false" mask="99.999">
    </p:inputMask>
    <!--
     <h:outputText value="Nome:*"/>      
     <p:inputText id="nome_usuario" value="#{usuarioBean.usuario_nome}" size="18"
                 required="true">

    </p:inputText>
     <h:outputText value="Senha:*"/>      
     <p:inputText id="usuario_senha" value="#{usuarioBean.usuario_senha}" size="18"
                 required="true">

    </p:inputText>
    <h:outputLabel value="Permissao:*" for="permissao"/>      
    <p:selectOneMenu id="permissao" value="" required="true">
                     <f:selectItem itemValue=""/>          
                     <f:selectItem itemValue="usuario" itemLabel="usuario"/>
                     <f:selectItem itemValue="administrador" itemLabel="administrador"/>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    -->

</h:panelGrid>
```

Essa é minha base de dados

> Table: funcionario
>   Columns:
>   cpf varchar(15) PK
>   nome varchar(200)
>   rg varchar(15)
>   orgaoExped varchar(3)
>   estadoCivil varchar(30)
>   sexo varchar(10)
>   cnh varchar(15)
>   titulo varchar(15)
>   zona int(11)
>   carteiraTrabalho varchar(15)
>   serieCTrabalho varchar(15)
>   cartResevista varchar(15)
>   serieResevista varchar(15)
>   cor varchar(10)
>   pis varchar(15)
>   conta_corrente varchar(11)
>   agencia_banco varchar(11)
>   nome_banco varchar(30)
>   numero_banco int(11)
>   cargo varchar(60)
>   dataExped date
>   dataDeNascimento date
>   secao varchar(3)

obs:todos os campos not null.

Classe Dao

```
public boolean selecionarFuncionario(Funcionario execute) throws Exception {

        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        try {
            String sql = "select * from funcionario where cpf = '?';";
            stmt = this.conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){

                execute.setCpf(rs.getString("cpf"));
                execute.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
                execute.setRg(rs.getString("rg"));
                execute.setOrgaoExped(rs.getString("orgaoExped"));
                execute.setDataExped(rs.getDate("dataExped"));
                execute.setDataDeNascimento(rs.getDate("dataDeNascimento"));
                execute.setCargo(rs.getString("cargo"));
                execute.setEstadoCivil(rs.getString("estadoCivil"));
                execute.setSexo(rs.getString("sexo"));
                execute.setCnh(rs.getString("cnh"));
                execute.setTitulo(rs.getString("titulo"));
                execute.setZona(rs.getInt("zona"));
                execute.setSecao(rs.getInt("secao"));
                execute.setCarteiraTrabalho(rs.getString("carteiraTrabalho"));
                execute.setSerieCTrabalho(rs.getString("serieCTrabalho"));
                execute.setCartResevista(rs.getString("cartResevista"));
                execute.setSerieResevista(rs.getString("serieResevista"));
                execute.setCor(rs.getString("cor"));
                execute.setPis(rs.getString("pis"));
                execute.setConta_corrente(rs.getString("conta_corrente"));
                execute.setAgencia_banco(rs.getString("agencia_banco"));
                execute.setNome_banco(rs.getString("nome_banco"));
                execute.setNumero_banco(rs.getInt("numero_banco"));
                }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FuncionarioDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        }
        return true;
    }
```

Controle

```
public String selecFuncionario() throws Exception{
      FuncionarioDAO cD = new FuncionarioDAO();
      cD.selecionarFuncionario(this.funcionario);
      return "/editar";
  }
```

Comment: Se alguém puder dar uma força eu agradeço muito,não estou conseguindo carregar os campos.

Comment: Resulta depois de executar.

Comment: 01-Aug-2016 13:52:58.814 INFO [http-apr-8080-exec-97] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start The start() method was called on component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ProjetoGrandeRecife]] after start() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.

Comment: Primeiro: Qual é o retorno disso aqui? 
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

Segundo, INFO [http-apr-8080-exec-97]...
Como diz aí, é só uma INFO, não é um erro.

Comment: No caso seria o retorno da query, para carregar os campos,para dai poder editar.

Comment: Sim, claro. Me expressei mal, só queria saber se a query está retornando os resultados corretamente. (:

Comment: Então ae é onde entra os parceiros do STACKOVERFLOW...pra está tudo certo mais mão consigo ver aonde estou errando.

Comment: desculpa...não. corrigindo

Comment: Então ae é onde entra os parceiros do STACKOVERFLOW...pra está tudo certo mais não consigo ver aonde estou errando.

Comment: "(...)só queria saber se a query está retornando os resultados (...)"

Comment: Não, aparece o resultado que coloquei logo ae em cima nos comentários.

Comment: E ae gente alguém pode me ajudar...

Answer (score 3):

Você está esquecendo de passar o CPF do funcionário como parametro da query.

```
String sql = "select * from funcionario where cpf = '?'";
stmt = this.conn.prepareStatement(sql);

stmt.setString(1, execute.getCpf());

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```